# How to enable lock detecting configs in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, compiling, configuration, deadlock

I am developing a program which causes deadlocks. And I want Ubuntu to warn about all the deadlocks in the kernel, so I can know if my program succeeds. It's required that kernel can detect deadlocks automatically. And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892822/how-to-use-lockdep-feature-in-linux-kernel-for-deadlock-detection says that I should enable CONFIG_LOCKDEP and CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING in `.config`. However, CONFIG_LOCKDEP and CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING both depend on CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC. When I enable these three options and compile, it gives me this error:

> Kernel built with CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC which is incompatible with the CDDL license and will prevent the module linking stage from succeeding. You must rebuild your kernel without this option enabled.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Could you explain why do you need that (to prevent solving an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/217657)) and what tells you this should work?

Comment: @Melebius  I updated

Comment: Thank you but this is not enough. Why should your program cause kernel deadlocks? Are you developing kernel modules, for example? And which documents say this? Please include links to them.

Comment: @Melebius I updated

Comment: The CDDL license is from ZFS, IIRC. Try disabling ZFS support.

Comment: @muru, How to disable zfs while building kernel